# Extract only the Pattern from Select-String

Tags: powershell

I have a directory containing several files. These files each have a lot of lines. In these files I have to find the string ".MLB".

So I managed to build the following command :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test\' -Include '*.txt' -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'MLB'
```

which seems to work. The problem is that it returns the whole line where my search appears which is very difficult to read.

I know that there is `-Context` to choose the number of line to display, but is it possible to do that with characters instead ? For example display only the 20 characters that precede the pattern.

I made some progress and tried the following:

`Select-String -Path 'D:\TEST\log1.txt' -Pattern 'mlb' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }`

This returns the following

```
mlb
mlb
MLB
mlb
MLB
```

The only thing I need now would be a way to display what precede before that. Example:

```
data01a.mlb
data.mlb
DATE FILE MLB
HR.mlb
```

Comment: It will be better, if you could add some examples or pattern to your original post.

Comment: If it only returned the matched pattern (`MLB`) how would that be useful? The cmdlet outputs the matched line to give you context however the object itself ([`MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0)) has many useful properties. You need to be more specific with your question

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I added my progress I hope that it can clarify a little

Comment: If the files can have spaces like `DATE FILE MLB HR.mlb` is not something you could easily predict with regex. How many spaces can the files have? What condition can be use to know when the actual file name you want to match starts?

Comment: by the look of it I think one space should be enough. So instead of `DATE FILE MLB` we could display `FILE MLB`. This should be enough. By the way, I've seen someone using something like `-Pattern '\w+pattern\w+'`
I tried '\w+mlb\w+'` but it doesn't display anything

Comment: I mean, PowerShell isn't going to understand context, so it won't be able to figure out file names really, especially with spaces in them, but you could grab text around MLB easily enough with RegEx with something like `'.{0,20}mlb'`. That should give you up to 20 characters before the mlb (less if it's near the start of the line).

Comment: Thank you MadTechnician, this is awesome. I think i'll be able to get what I need now !